# HTML resizing image based on it's size

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

I encountered this problem while making an online shopping mall page.

Most of the photos uploaded to my db have different sizes and I had to resize them all. But when I did, some of the pictures' resolutions became really bad when I set all of their height the same.

I wanna add something like an `if` clause that determines size of the image then resizes only the images which are bigger than the given size.

I want to add something looks like this, I guess:

```
if (img height < 300px) {
   img height = "100px";
} else {
   img height = "400px";
}
```

Here's my current code:

```
<ul class="prdList column4">
        <li class="item" id="anchorBoxId_{$product_no}">
            <div class="box">
                <span class="chk"><input type="checkbox" class="{$product_compare_class} {$product_compare_display|display}" /></span>
                <a href="/product/detail.html{$param}" name="anchorBoxName_{$product_no}"><img src="{$image_big}"  id="{$image_medium_id}" alt="" class="thumb" /></a>
                <div class="status">
                    <div class="icon">{$soldout_icon} {$recommend_icon} {$new_icon} {$product_icons} {$benefit_icons}</div>
                    <div class="button"><div class="option">{$option_preview_icon}</div> {$basket_icon} {$zoom_icon}</div>
                </div>
                <p class="name">
                    <a href="/product/detail.html{$param}" class="{$product_name_display|display}"><strong class="title {$product_name_title_display|display}">{$product_name_title} :</strong> {$product_name}</a>
                </p>
                <ul module="product_ListItem">
                    <li class="{$item_display|display}"><strong class="title {$item_title_display|display}">{$item_title} :</strong> {$item_content}</li>
                    <li class="{$item_display|display}"><strong class="title {$item_title_display|display}">{$item_title} :</strong> {$item_content}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="item" id="anchorBoxId_{$product_no}">
            <div class="box">
                <span class="chk"><input type="checkbox" class="{$product_compare_class} {$product_compare_display|display}" /></span>
                <a href="/product/detail.html{$param}" name="anchorBoxName_{$product_no}"><img src="{$image_big}" id="{$image_medium_id}" alt="" class="thumb" /></a>
                <div class="status">
                    <div class="icon">{$soldout_icon} {$recommend_icon} {$new_icon} {$product_icons} {$benefit_icons}</div>
                    <div class="button"><div class="option">{$option_preview_icon}</div> {$basket_icon} {$zoom_icon}</div>
                </div>
                <p class="name">
                    <a href="/product/detail.html{$param}" class="{$product_name_display|display}"><strong class="title {$product_name_title_display|display}">{$product_name_title} :</strong> {$product_name}</a>
                </p>
                <ul module="product_ListItem">
                    <li class="{$item_display|display}"><strong class="title {$item_title_display|display}">{$item_title} :</strong> {$item_content}</li>
                    <li class="{$item_display|display}"><strong class="title {$item_title_display|display}">{$item_title} :</strong> {$item_content}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You're better off resizing them manually with a simple image tool before uploading to your DB

Comment: @codemax I guess it is sellers who upload the image. Forcing sellers to upload specific sizes of images are a simple solution but not user friendly.

Comment: I'm resizing all the new images i upload now but i can't do anything with previously posted images because they are way too many and i can't fix all of them manually =(

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add something looks like this, I guess:

```
if (img height < 300px) {
  img height = "100px";
} else {
  img height = "400px";
}
```

You guess it right.
You just need to find the functions to detect and change image size.

Where to find these functions

First check the function reference in official PHP manual.

Then you will find a dedicated section on image processing:

[Image Processing and Generation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php)

It turns out that several libraries provide required functions. 
For example, if you are using GD, it offers `getimagesize` and `imagescale`.
Gmagick and ImageMagick have similar functions, just with different names.

Comment: Thanks for your response and correcting my wrong grammar =) I will try to study more about those references you have provided to me to fix my issues